# Get Element ID by String it Contains using Plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get an elemnts ID based on the string it contains?

```
<span id="th67">This the string I need to match</span>
```

I can't make use of JQuery or any other Javascript library to do this.

I need to do this for a selenium test.

I didn't realise how useless I am in JS without my libraries!

Thanks all for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you know what kind of tag you're looking for, you can just do:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'), targetId;
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
  if (spans[i].innerText === stringToMatch) {
    // found it ...
    targetId = spans[i].id;
    break;
  }
}
if (targetId) {
  // ... do whatever ...
}
```

If you want to get fancy you could construct an xpath query, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

If the browsers you're targeting support XPath you can do a simple XPath query:

```
// Find an element by the text it contains, optionally
// starting at specified parent element.
function getElementByText( text, ctx)
{
  return document.evaluate("//*[.='"+text+"']", 
     ctx || document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
}
```

Then just run

```
var myElement = getElementByText( "This is the string I need to match" );
if ( myElement )
{
  // do something with myElement.id
}
```

Comment: That's elegant. Any way I can get all elements containing a string? I tried `while (myElement = getElementByText(searchString))`, but it seems to generate an endless loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple recursive function that will do it:

```
function findByText(node, text) {
    if(node.nodeValue == text) {
        return node.parentNode;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var returnValue = findByText(node.childNodes[i], text);
        if (returnValue != null) {
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Use it as:

```
var target = findByText(document, "This the string I need to match");
```

This will end up with either `target` being `null`, or it being a DOM node whose id you can get with `target.id`.

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kApJb/).